# Trailer Lighting Using a Dynamo Hub

Tags: wheels, rims, wheel-building, lighting, taillight

I have a [B.o.B. Yak trailer](http://www.bobgear.com/bike-trailers/yak) which uses a ISO 305 mm BSD rim. I'd like to build up a wheel for the trailer using a dynamo hub (perhaps a [Sanyo H27](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/sanyo.asp)) so that I could have lights on the trailer.

I know I could use battery lights, but I've become very fond of not having to change or even think about batteries (a lot of our biking is "car replacement" rides around town, so it is really nice to just know that you've got lights). Seems like this would also give me power to charge a phone or other small device since the draw of a rear light will be well below the capacity of the dynamo.

A wheel built on 305 mm rims is going to turn just about twice as fast as a wheel built on a 622 mm (700C) rim. My impression is that the output voltage of the hub increases with speed – and that the output of modern hubs are regulated. So I'm wondering what issues I might run into using a dynamo generator as a power source.
Some that I've thought of are:

- Availability of rims (the hub is available in 28, 32, and 36 hole drillings). A rim drilled for a presta valve would be nice since it would mean that a single pump would serve for bike and trailer without having to convert the head.
- Availability of suitable hubs. The speed difference between the bike wheels and the trailer wheels has been pointed out, but I haven't been able to find data on the hub behavior. I would assume that dynamo hubs would be designed to tolerate a full range of biking speeds – say up to at least 65 or 80 kph (40 or 50 mph). Since the trailer is placarded with a speed limit of 40 kph I'd been thinking I was within bounds.
- Finding short spokes. By my calculations I'd need a 110 mm spoke to do a radial pattern and could go up to around 155 mm doing a 4-cross. Seems like recumbents and BMX bikes would mean that spokes this short are available somewhere. Failing that could I have them custom cut from straight gauge spokes?

So it seems like the big issue is the hub? Does anybody know the limits on modern hub designs? So far e-mail queries have gone unanswered…

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, however:  http://www.niagaracycle.com/categories/wheels/rims/16 and http://www.niagaracycle.com/categories/wheels/wheels/16

Comment: Why not use the existing rim and just replace the hub?

Comment: Also, you could probably also salvage something from an old kid's bike as it seems to be the same rim size as a 16 inch children's bike. It probably won't be drilled for presta, but you can get grommets to fill the gap.

Comment: @Kibbee I could, but since I'd also need to get spokes and go to the trouble to take the wheel apart it seemed a bit nicer to get a decent rim drilled for a presta valve if I could find one. The build of the trailer frame seems pretty decent, but the wheel and other accessories not so much.

Comment: Presta valve on a 16" tube is going to be hard to fine in the field (at least in the US).  I found some on Amazon, but I doubt Walmart (and most LBS) would have them.  I would go for the schrader drilled hole since it would cover both valve types.

Comment: I think Peter White carries 16" presta tubes, I'd really like to find some because that would mean only having to carry one pump (or not having to convert pump heads).

Comment: Some recumbents use use ISO 305. Alexrims makes some rims which are 16" presta but I don't know how many spokes.

Comment: You must really hate changing batteries.  That is lot of expense and trouble to avoid a pair of batteries that cost $1 and last 40 hours.

Comment: I do :-) Plus it seems like a fun project.

Comment: Are you sure that hub will be ok in such a small rim? Most dynamos are regulated to put out the standard voltage over a given rpm range. Your link mentions using it in a 26in wheel; a 305 etrto would spin a good deal faster.

Comment: [This site](http://www.kstoerz.com/freespoke/hub/259) suggests it's intended for 26"-29" wheels only. Depending on the OLN of the frame, you may need something intended for Moulton/Brompton or similar.

Comment: Have you considered a solar panel on the trailer and a rechargeable light?

Comment: @dlu, Asking if a hub dyno can be used in a 16" wheel would make for a good question.

Comment: @JHCL, wheel speed would be just about twice a 700C. So, 40 kph (25 MPH) on the trailer would be about 80 kph on a road bike, or 72 with 26" wheels. That seems like it might not be outside of the design parameters of the hub, but I haven't been able to find any actual data.

Comment: @dlu - Obviously it's the lights (& bulbs) that you'd need to worry about. I'm no electrician, but I daresay it's possible to rig up some external regulation circuitry to stop them blowing on your favourite descent. You did say it seems like a fun project! In fact, if you look further down the [page you linked to](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/sanyo.asp), it talks about overvoltage protection for the lights. Note the comments on increased (magnetic) drag on smaller wheels, as well.

Comment: @BPugh Bromptons have 16" wheels and are available with dynamo hubs, so yes, you can use a hub dynamo in a 16" wheel. (Which doesn't necessarily mean you can use one in a Yak trailer with just a rear light.)

Answer (score 4):

[Velocity](http://www.velocityusa.com/) definitely make 305 rims, and at least when they were in Australia would use their available extrusions to make semi-custom rims to order - most often so you can get the number of spokes/drilling pattern you want, but they would also make odd sizes if the extrusion was compatible. But [they've moved to the US](http://craftworx.com.au/about-us) and I have no idea what they're like now as far as custom builds go.

[SJS in the USA](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/rims-16-305-dept163/?geoc=au) also stock 305 rims and I found quite a [lot of hits just using google](https://www.google.com/search?q=305%20bicycle%20rim) so decent rims in that size seem to be fairly widely available.

Schwalbe make bicycle tubes in a wide range of sizes with both Schrader and Presta valves - if you can find what you want on [this page](http://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/tubes/all) your LBS will be able to get it (although it may take a while). There are quite a few choices in 305mm presta tubes.

You may have more problems getting a dynamo that's designed for a 305 wheel. The circumference is half that of a 622 (27") wheel so it spins twice as fast at the same road speed, and unlike a childs bike your trailer is going to be used at normal road speeds. [SON make dynamos](http://www.nabendynamo.de/produkte/son_xs_neu_en.html) for folding bikes with small wheels so if the Sanyo doesn't work I suggest trying SON. I have one and like it, although I had to replace the bearings after about 50Mm.

Comment: 50 Mm? Is that 5,000,000 meters (5,000 km)?

Comment: yep, that's how the metric system works ;) And that's 250000 furlongs for people using imperial units.

Comment: A question for the OP is: how much does the trailer slow them down? If a dynamo can deal with fast road speeds on 26" wheels, the rpm on a fully loaded touring trailer with small wheels probably won't be twice that. A decent charging circuit would be needed in any case.

Comment: @Mσᶎ, I was pretty sure I was getting my numbers right. That seems like a very short bearing life. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @ChrisH, the trailer is placarded with a speed limit of 40 kph (25 mph). I don't feel like I need / want to go much faster than that with it. I've been wondering the same thing – I don't do it, but it seems like there must be folks who hit 80 kph (50 mph) on downhills pretty regularly.

Comment: The sustained speed might be more important than the peak speed, and in a front wheel it will get more cooling air flow, but I'd *guess* you'd be within the margin for what it can handle.

Comment: @dlu Ooops, 50Mm is 50,000 km, you slipped a decimal on me. I'm not sure whether anything actually did go wrong, because that doesn't seem particularly short to me. The Rohloff bearings are an oil exit path so they get lubricated, where the dyno ones only have the grease they were shipped with. Either way, $100-odd for new bearings every 10 years seems reasonable.